# How to add a blank space in HTML

Tags: html

I just started learning HTML yesterday and I am experiencing with it, does anyone know how can I add ablank space between texts?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

in html you can use `&nbsp;` that you can use into of some text but if you want to add between divs you need to use css

Answer (score 1):

you can use &nbsp inside your header or paragraph tags to insert one blank space or   for two blank spaces.